# iOS - How can I perform the visual effects like Clear app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-animation, visual-effects

I was wondering how can I make visual effects like the ones in the Clear app or the one you can perform in the Twitter app on iPad (by pinching between two rows in a tableview) ?

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a sample project on Github, JTGestureBasedTableViewDemo

Link: https://github.com/mystcolor/JTGestureBasedTableViewDemo

Answer (score 1):

You could look into this component:

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/pulltorefreshtransform

See how the top row transform is implemented and use the idea for your needs. You'll probably need to use pinch gestures to make this work like in "Clear"

Hope I gave you a good starting point. Good luck